# how do you call a function that breaks down on y?

Tags: terminology

How do you call a (linear) function (or the point), which breaks down to 0 on ordinate (axis y), as soon as you breach a certain x1 value?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you want the graph to have the vertical line above $x_1$, or you just mean that the graph quits at $x_1$?

Comment: From what you say @rschwieb, I imply it's not the same. I want to indicate, that if value x is greater than x1, y always results 0.

Comment: OK, yes, $0$ after $x_1$. But you did not actually mean to draw the vertical line then?

Comment: True. That is my bad. It entails that having x1 could result in any y covered by that vertical slope section. total non-sense. sorry for that, folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could describe it as *[piecewise linear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function)*, and write it e.g. $f:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x)=\begin{cases}mx+y_1-mx_1 & \text{if } 0 \leq x < x_1 \\ 0 & \text{if } x \geq x_1 \end{cases}$$ where $m$ is the slope (in this case, it'll be negative).

---

If "break down" means we want the function undefined (instead of $0$), we can define the domain of the function as $[0,x_1]$.

Comment: I think the phrase "piecewise linear" is usually used to mean that the function is not only linear on "pieces" but also continuous, even at the endpoints of the pieces.

Comment: Dear @AndreasBlass I don't believe the inclusion of continuity is necessarily standard. I recall seeing several textbooks ask the student to "pick values for these constants to make this piecewise linear function continuous" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assumming you meant a vertical segment at $x=x_1$, this is not (the graph of) a function at all, and even less (if that were possible) a *linear* function. A (non-linear) function could make a jump at $x=x_1$, but it would need to have a unique value at $x_1$ (not a whole range of values). Your description also suggests it would have to have (unique) values beyond $x_1$ (it wouldn't have to if you defined a function with domain $[0,x_1]$ but I don't think you intended that).

Comment: I wouldn't say "not the graph of a function *at all*" because one could feasibly consider it as a function *of $y$*, but of course we're all agreed it's not a function *of $x$*. I guess some readers might not accept any other variable than the one on the horizontal $x$ axis as a candidate for input, and that would be OK too: this is just for the rest of us.